# Adding Azure Boards in GCC High?

Tags: gcc, cloud, azure-boards

So, I'm working in an enviornment that utilizes GCC High/365 Gov't Community Cloud High. I haven't seen any documentation online (or I could be missing it entirely) on if it can support Azure boards? We'd love to set up an Azure Board for our company branches to more effectively communicate, along with general bug reporting and issue tracking. Does GCC High support Azure Boards?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently supported, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops#prerequisites) article and [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-available-for-gcc-high/1400027) community post.

> Glad to see you in Developer Community!
>
> Azure Devops service is not supported for GCC High accounts. As per
> our doc mentioned below:
>
> Ensure you're using Azure AD Public. Connecting Azure DevOps Services
> organizations to Azure AD Government and accessing Azure DevOps
> Services with user accounts from Azure AD Government isn't supported.